# Slowdown RecyclerView when approaching the end of the items

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Now im use the

```
recycler.smoothScrollByPosition
```

I already change scroll speed in custom LayoutManager, but i need to slowdown recycler, then he will be at the last elements of item

Comment: Can you please share the layout code

Comment: val linearSmoothScroller: LinearSmoothScroller = object : LinearSmoothScroller(
            recyclerView.context
        ) {
            override fun calculateSpeedPerPixel(displayMetrics: DisplayMetrics): Float {
                return speed / displayMetrics.densityDpi
            }
        }